# Using operators, how to set a variable equal to one of two other variables depending on which one has a value, in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, logic, operators

When there are only two states for instance variable "a", either it has a value or not, and there is only one possible state for instance variable "b", it has a value.  I can set "a" equal to "b" if "a" does not have a value via:

```rb
@a = nil
@b = "world"

def set_a
    @a ||= @b
end

set_a

p @a
 => "world"
```

```rb
@a = "hello"
@b = "world"

def set_a
    @a ||= @b
end

set_a

p @a
 => "hello"
```

But, what if there is more than one option for "a" to be set to?  For example, I want to set instance variable "a" to either "b" or "c" depending on which has a value.  In the program, only either "b" or "c" will have a value, always one but never both.  Is there a way, using operators to write something like the following:

```rb
if @a == nil
   if @b == nil
      @a = @c
   else
      @a = @b
   end
end
```

I was trying to write something that looks like this:

```rb
def set_a
    @a ||= (@b || @c)
end
```

But, if @a had a value it would remain. Which is what I want.  However, if @a was nil, then it would not take on the value of either @b or @c, it would remain nil.

Thank you for you time.

Comment: Are A, B and C really constants? Or just simple placeholders for ordinary variables?

Comment: You need to include actual data in your question. As it stands, there are a lot of reasons your code and logic could fail, and "strange actions" doesn't provide any useful data. Define your actual data, and show the actual errors or unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
Module.const_defined?(:A) ? A : (B == true ? B : C)
```

to obtain the value of `A`.

```
A not defined
B = true
Module.const_defined?(:A) ? A : (B == true ? B : C)
  #=> true
```

```
A not defined
B = false
Module.const_defined?(:A) ? A : (B == true ? B : C)
  #=> 42
```

```
A = "cat"
B = false
C = 42
Module.const_defined?(:A) ? A : (B == true ? B : C)
  #=> "cat"
```

See [Module#const_defined?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-const_defined-3F).

Comment: We don't know if the OP has actually defined any of the constants, so any of them could raise NameError. He'd probably be better off using instance variables, since those are auto-vivified.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs, I interpreted "Only B or C will have a value at any given time. Sometimes A will have a value sometimes not." as meaning that B and C have been defined. The question is specifically about constants--the OP may just be curious and have no intention of using the code in an app--so I didn't address any  broader questions. I find that questions driven by curiosity are often highly educational.

Comment: I wasn't criticizing, although it may have come across that way. I was just trying to note for other readers and the OP that his question lacks certain essential details, and your answer assumes that both *B* and *C* are `defined?`, which is an assumption that may not be bourne out in the actual problem. I generally like your approach to answers as teachable moments; I was just pointing out some underlying assumptions in this answer that some people might not grasp intuitively if they aren't experienced Rubyists. I think your answer is good, but needs to check all 3 constants are `defined?`.

Comment: BTW, it's not that they need to be checked if the OP's *stated* rules are all valid. It's that the problem he outlined means any of his three constants might be called upon at some point, so if *any* of them are undefined then he's likely to get NameError. Something like `%w[A B C].map { Module.const_defined? _1 }.any?` wouldn't help because  even just `A ||= B` will raise unless *B* is defined, so *C* would never get evaluated even if it were defined.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for your feedback.  I have updated my question.  Let me know if you think I need to add more info to make it more useful to others.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs Thank you for your feedback.  I have updated my question.  Let me know if you think I need to add more info to make it more useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Constants and local variables will raise NameError if not defined. You probably want to use instance variables instead, as they are auto-vivified as `nil` when referenced even if they haven't been assigned to yet. For example:

```
@a ||= (@b || @c)
#=> nil
```

If either *@a* or *@b* are truthy, then things will probably work as you expect. However, if all three variables are falsey, then *@a* will be assigned the value of *@c* even if *@c* evaluates as `nil` or `false`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Then *@a* will be falsey, and `(@b || @c)` will be short-circuit evaluated and the expression's result assigned to *@a*. In that case, *@a* might still end up being falsey, depending on what's in *@b* or *@c*, but it *will* be assigned a value. If you don't know what's in the other variables, it's hard to differentiate which values are `nil` or `false`, but according to the logic in my answer *@a* would only be falsey if all three values are falsey since *@c* would be the last value evaluated and therefore assigned to *@a*.

Comment: Yes, my brain changed the question, which it's been doing with increasing frequency of late.